# select query from table with area sum

Tags: sql

[image]

How can the query be written to get sum(multiply) of the areas before it becomes 10

for first row i need to take 8*6=48 and on second row (10-8)*5 = 10
and sum will be 58

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Add its tag.)

Comment: Where does the number `10` come from?

Comment: 10 is predefined number. dbms is postgresql